# D3 ordinal scale zoom by rectangle not able to make it work

Tags: d3.js

After googling a lot, I haven't been able to find how to implement zoom by drawing rectangle when having an ordinal scale for both x and y-axis.

using default `d3.behaviour.zoom()` I can zoom/pan using mousewheel/double-click. But I am trying to draw a rectangle on the chart and then trigger zoom on a selected area.

basically, I am trying to zoom heatmap chart with ordinal scales by drawing a rectangle.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhrubs/hzyqek1n/)

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", zoomHandler);

xRange = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, width]);
  yRange = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([height, 0]);

function zoomHandler(){
  console.log('zoomed');
  var translate = zoom.translate(),
               scale = zoom.scale();

   var tx = Math.min(0, Math.max(translate[0], width - width * scale));
   var ty = Math.min(0, Math.max(translate[1], height - height * scale));

   zoom.translate([tx, ty]);

   xRange.rangeBands([d3.event.translate[0], d3.event.translate[0] + (width * d3.event.scale)])
   yRange.rangeBands([d3.event.translate[1] + (height * d3.event.scale), d3.event.translate[1]])

   svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis)
   svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis)

   svg.selectAll(".tile")
           .attr("width", xRange.rangeBand())
           .attr("height", yRange.rangeBand())
           .attr("x", function (d) {
               return xRange(d.x);
           })
           .attr("y", function (d) {
               return yRange(d.y);
           })

}

svg.on("mousedown", function() {
    console.log('mousedown ####');
    var e = this,
        origin = d3.mouse(e),
        rect = svg.append("rect").attr("class", "zoom");
    d3.select("body").classed("noselect", true);
    origin[0] = Math.max(0, Math.min(width, origin[0]));
    origin[1] = Math.max(0, Math.min(height, origin[1]));
    d3.select(window)
        .on("mousemove.zoomRect", function() {
          var m = d3.mouse(e);
          m[0] = Math.max(0, Math.min(width, m[0]));
          m[1] = Math.max(0, Math.min(height, m[1]));
          rect.attr("x", Math.min(origin[0], m[0]))
              .attr("y", Math.min(origin[1], m[1]))
              .attr("width", Math.abs(m[0] - origin[0]))
              .attr("height", Math.abs(m[1] - origin[1]));
        })
        .on("mouseup.zoomRect", function() {
          d3.select(window).on("mousemove.zoomRect", null).on("mouseup.zoomRect", null);
          d3.select("body").classed("noselect", false);
          var m = d3.mouse(e);
          m[0] = Math.max(0, Math.min(width, m[0]));
          m[1] = Math.max(0, Math.min(height, m[1]));
          if (m[0] !== origin[0] && m[1] !== origin[1]) {
            console.log('zoom rect');
            //here i need to trigger zoom translate/scale event, don't know how to trigger that.
          }
          rect.remove();
          refresh();
        }, true);
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Would be great to see definition of your globals such as `svg` and perhaps have some HTML to make a functional example of this.

Comment: stop using d3v3, use d3v5 brushXY to draw the rect and get callbacks and set the zoom accordingly based on selected region, or just use d3.zoom

Comment: here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dhrubs/hzyqek1n/

Comment: I am looking for a solution in d3v3. Something similar to http://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/3689931 but in ordinal scale.